# Criteria for existence of real intersection between a cubic and a conic plane curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space, intersection-theory

I am wondering if you could give a (easy?) criteria when a (projective) plane conic and cubic curve intersect at real points? For simplicity let us assume that these curves are smooth (although I am also interested in the general case as well).

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) `R=QQ[x,y,z]`
`S=QQ[x,y]`
`f=map(S,R,{x, y, 1})`
`g=f random(2,R)`
`h=f random(3,R)`
`resultant(g,h,x)`
The $y$-coordinates of the intersection points are the roots of this (in general) degree six polynomial. It would be sufficient for this to have six real roots.

Comment: why would having the $y$-coordinate of the intersection real mean that the $x$-coordinate is also real? degree of the resultant is $6$. Well for random choice you will get (I assume) at least a real solution to the sextic polynomial but this is just a general case.

Comment: Demand it for the $x$-s as well by taking the resultant wrt $y$.

Comment: The intersection points are a zero-dimensional variety and by the theorem referred to in [a recent question on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310439/on-the-proof-of-a-zero-dimensional-scheme-in-mathbbpn-is-always-affine) the a priori just complex points with multiplicity are affine. The citeria for reality remain the reality of the roots of the now guaranteed degree six polynomials in $x$ and $y$.